# Convert Object to string in codeiniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter

My model have 3 methods, the values returned from get_state_name() and get_district_name() is object type, how can i converte it to string??
when i bind the values to form an address i got this error

> Message : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

can anybody help me??

```
get_job_address();

get_state_name();

get_district_name();
```

here is my code

```
public function get_job_address($location_state_id,$district_name_id) {
    $state=$this->get_state_name($location_state_id);
    $district=$this->get_district_name($district_name_id);
    return $district.', '.$state;
}
public function get_state_name($location_state_id) {
    $this->db->select('country_name');
    $this->db->where('sid',$location_state_id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query=$this->db->get('countries');
    return $query->row();
}
public function get_district_name($district_name_id) {
    $this->db->select('state_name');
    $this->db->where('sid',$location_name_id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query=$this->db->get('states');
    return $query->row();
}
```

Comment: try $query->result_array(); or $query->row_array();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return the value of the field you want like:

```
public function get_state_name($location_state_id) 
{
    $this->db->select('country_name');
    $this->db->where('sid',$location_state_id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query=$this->db->get('countries');

    // check to make sure you got a result
    if ( $query->num_rows() == 1 ) 
    {  
        $row = $query->row(); 
        return $row->state_name ; 
    }
    // if no result return false
    else { return false; }
}
```

also review your third method, get_district_name(), the where is calling the wrong variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is here:

```
$district=$this->get_district_name($district_name_id);
return $district.', '.$state;
```

> $district

is an std class object and you cannot concat an string to an object.